# Typesetting a large matrix in LaTeX

Tags: latex, matrix, amsmath

I have a 3x12 matrix I'd like to input into my LaTeX (with amsmath) document but LaTeX seems to choke when the matrix gets larger than 3x10:

```
\begin{equation}
\textbf{e} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&-1&-1&-1&-1\\
1&-1&0&0&1&1&-1&-1&0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&1&-1&1&-1&1&-1&1&-1&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

The error: **Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.** tells me that I have more `&` than the `bmatrix` environment can handle. Is there a proper way to handle this? It also seems that the alignment for 1's and the -1's are different, is that also expected of the `bmatrix`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the `amsmath` documentation (`texdoc amsmath`):

> The amsmath package provides some
>   environments for matrices beyond the
>   basic array environment of LATEX. The
>   pmatrix, bmatrix, Bmatrix, vmatrix and
>   Vmatrix   have    (respectively)  ( ),    [
>   ],    { },    | |,    and ∥
>   ∥ delimiters  built   in. For naming
>   consistency there is a matrix
>   environment sans delimiters. This is
>   not entirely redundant with the array
>   environment; the matrix environments
>   all use more economical horizontal
>   spacing than the rather prodigal
>   spacing of the array environment.
>   Also, unlike the array environment,
>   you don’t have to give column
>   specifications for any of the matrix
>   environments; by default you can have
>   up to 10 centered columns.    (If you
>   need left or right alignment in a
>   column or other special formats you
>   must resort to array.)

i.e. `bmatrix` defaults to a 10 column maximum.

A footnote adds

> More precisely: The maximum number of
>   columns in a matrix is determined by
>   the counter MaxMatrixCols (normal
>   value = 10), which you can change if
>   necessary using LATEX’s \setcounter or
>   \addtocounter commands.

Comment: Wonderful! This was exactly what I was looking for, I didn't realize one could change the column maximum. As for the right-alignment, I've since found a nice workaround that still allows the bmatrix command - I'll post it in my own solution.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem, good question! I was computing character tables in representation theory and even with quite small groups you end up easily with large matrices. Thanks for posting/answering this question!

Answer (score 6):

If you came to this page looking for the exact command (thanks to Scott Wales for the answer), you want this in your preamble:

```
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
```

Where you can replace `20` with the maximum number of columns you want.

Comment: thanks, this was the most concise, working answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Scott is correct, but I've since learned you *can* override the alignment. Taken from http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/matrix-align-left-right/

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][c]{\hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols #1}}
\makeatother
```

Now allows the command:

```
\begin{bmatrix}[r] ....
```

to have right-alignment!

Comment: I believe you can also just use `bmatrix*` environment from the `mathtools` package to achieve the same thing, at least according to the wikibook:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Matrices_and_arrays

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `bmatrix` you can use `+bmatrix` from the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\textbf{e} = 
\begin{+bmatrix} 
1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&-1&-1&-1&-1\\
1&-1&0&0&1&1&-1&-1&0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&1&-1&1&-1&1&-1&1&-1&0&0
\end{+bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]